# Convert image of graph to Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, game

The board game Ticket To Ride has a board readily represented as a graph.
I have an image of a graph (taken from [BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/34856/ttr-europe-network-analysis)) that I'd like to convert to graph in Mathematica for further analysis.

[image: TTR-E]

I've used the following code which does produce a graph but it has too many (100) vertices.

```
img=Import["TTR-E.png"];
g = MorphologicalGraph[Binarize[ColorNegate[img]]];
```

I've tried the following to clean it up but it doesn't produce the GUI window as it should. In any case I'd like to convert it without such intervention.

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
GraphEdit[g]
```

As a bonus I'd like to import the thick edges as two separate edges and the red (tunnels) and blue(ferries) edges with special labels. Eventually I can add edge lengths (route lengths), colors for edges (route colors) and vertex labels (city names).

Comment: This question should remain closed unless OP specifies `Edgeweight` in the import parameters, or something else to differentiate it from the linked question.

Answer (score 5):

On my system, `MorphologicalGraph` with the default `Method` can't seem to find all the vertices of the graph. I ended up with the following to get an initial graph that at least has all the vertices:

```
g=MorphologicalGraph[
    Thinning[Binarize @ ColorNegate @ image, 3, Method->"MedialAxis"]
]
```

[image: graph]

This version of the graph had even more vertices than yours:

```
VertexCount @ g
(* 163 *)
```

Rather than trying to adjust the `Image` so that `MorphologicalGraph` would produce fewer vertices, I decided to post-process the `Graph` to eliminate extra vertices. First, here are the initial vertices:

```
vertexRules = Thread @ Rule[
    PropertyValue[g, VertexCoordinates],
    VertexList[g]
];
```

Now, using the fact that there should be 47 vertices, we can use `FindClusters` to group vertices that should be the same:

```
clusters = FindClusters[vertexRules, 47];
```

If I just use the `FindClusters[vertexRules]` I get 48 clusters, because one of the vertices at the top right gets displaced too far from the others. At any rate, using these clusters, we can come up with a list of rules to eliminate extra vertices:

```
substitutes = Flatten @ Replace[
    clusters,
    {
        {_}->Sequence[],
        {a__,b_}:>Thread[Rule[{a},b]]
    },
    {1}
]
```

Using the above rules, we can replace the vertices in the original edge list with a representative from each cluster:

```
edges = DeleteDuplicates @ DeleteCases[
    EdgeList[g] /. substitutes,
    x_<->x_
]
```

After replacing the vertices with the representatives, there are many self-loops and multiedges that need to be pruned, which explains the need for `DeleteDuplicates` and `DeleteCases`. Now, all that's left to do is to position the vertices in the right spots:

```
graph = Graph[
    edges,
    VertexShapeFunction -> "Square",
    VertexSize -> Large,
    VertexCoordinates -> SortBy[vertexRules, Last][[VertexList[edges], 1]]
]
```

[image: final graph]